# how can I fix an error of undefined variables even if they are defined?

Tags: reactjs, variables, declaration

Can anybody please helps me to figure out why I keep getting an error about undefined variables (emailRef,passwordRef,passwordConfirmRef) even if I did define them.
here's the code:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { Form, Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'


export default function Signup(){
    
        const emailRef = useRef();
        const passwordRef = useRef();
        const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();
        return (
        <>
            <Card>
                  <Card.Body>
                      <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Inscrivez-vous!</h2>
                      <Form>
                        <Form.Group id="email">
                            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group id="password">
                            <Form.Label>Mot de passe</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group id="password-confirm">
                            <Form.Label>Confirmation du mot de passe</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordConfirmRef} required/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button className="w-100" type="submit">S'inscrire</Button>
                      </Form> 
    
                  </Card.Body>
                  
              </Card>
              <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
                 Vous avez déjà un compte? Connectez-vous!  
              </div>  
            </>
        )
    }
```

Comment: please check your react , react-dom and react-bootstrap installations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't install bootstrap. Install it first then it will work.

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@4.6.0
```

Not its working. [image]